# How to convert semicolon delimited file to nested dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to convert a semicolon delimited file to a nested dict. Been working on this quite a bit this morning and guessing I am overlooking something simple:

### Input (Sample)

This is actually about 200 lines long. Just a small sample.

```
key;name;desc;category;type;action;range;duration;skill;strain_mod;apt_bonus
ambiencesense;Ambience Sense;This sleight provides the async with an instinctive sense about an area and any potential threats nearby. The async receives a +10 modifier to all Investigation, Perception, Scrounging, and Surprise Tests.;psi-chi;passive;automatic;self;constant;;0;
cogboost;Cognitive Boost;The async can temporarily elevate their cognitive performance.;psi-chi;active;quick;self;temp;;-1;{'COG': 5}
```

### Current Output

```
[['key',
  'name',
  'desc',
  'category',
  'type',
  'action',
  'range',
  'duration',
  'skill',
  'strain_mod',
  'apt_bonus'],
 ['ambiencesense',
  'Ambience Sense',
  'This sleight provides the async with an instinctive sense about an area and any potential threats nearby. The async receives a +10 modifier to all Investigation, Perception, Scrounging, and Surprise Tests.',
  'psi-chi',
  'passive',
  'automatic',
  'self',
  'constant',
  '',
  '0',
  ''],
 ['cogboost',
  'Cognitive Boost',
  'The async can temporarily elevate their cognitive performance.',
  'psi-chi',
  'active',
  'quick',
  'self',
  'temp',
  '',
  '-1',
  "{'COG': 5}"]]
```

### Desired Output

```
blahblah = {
     'ambiencesense': {
         'name': 'Ambiance Sense'
         'desc': 'This sleight provides the async with an instinctive sense about an area and any potential threats nearby. The async receives a +10 modifier to all Investigation, Perception, Scrounging, and Surprise Tests.',
         'category': 'psi-chi',
         'type': 'passive',
         'action': 'automatic',
         'range': 'self',
         'duration': 'constant',
         'skill': '',
         'strain_mod': '0',
         'apt_bonus': '',
         },     
     'cogboost': {
         'name': 'Cognitive Boost'
         'desc': 'The async can temporarily elevate their cognitive performance.',
         'category': 'psi-chi',
         'type': 'active',
         'action': 'quick',
         'range': 'self',
         'duration': 'temp',
         'skill': '',
         'strain_mod': '-1',
         'apt_bonus': 'COG', 5',
         },
         ...
```

### Script (Nonfunctional)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Usage: ./csvdict.py <filename to convert to dict> <file to output>

import csv
import sys
import pprint

def parse(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
        dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(), delimiters=';')
        csvfile.seek(0)
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect)
        dict_list = []

        for line in reader:
            dict_list.append(line)
        return dict_list

        new_dict = {}

        for item in dict_list:
            key = item.pop('key')
            new_dict[key] = item

output = parse(sys.argv[1])

with open(sys.argv[2], 'wt') as out:
    pprint.pprint(output, stream=out)
```

### Working Script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Usage: ./csvdict.py <input filename> <output filename>

import sys
import pprint

file_name = sys.argv[1]
data = {}
error = 'Incorrect number of arguments.\nUsage: ./csvdict.py <input filename> <output filename>'

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print(error)
else:

    with open(file_name, 'r') as test_fh:
        header_line = next(test_fh)
        header_line = header_line.strip()
        headers = header_line.split(';')

        index_headers = {index:header for index, header in enumerate(headers)}

        for line in test_fh:
            line = line.strip()
            values = line.split(';')
            index_vals = {index:val for index, val in enumerate(values)}
            data[index_vals[0]] = {index_headers[key]:value for key, value in index_vals.items() if key != 0}

    with open(sys.argv[2], 'wt') as out:
        pprint.pprint(data, stream=out)
```

The only thing this doesn't handle well is the embedded dicts. Any ideas how to clean this up? (see apt_bonus)

```
 'cogboost': {'action': 'quick',
              'apt_bonus': "{'COG': 5}",
              'category': 'psi-chi',
              'desc': 'The async can temporarily elevate their cognitive performance.',
              'duration': 'temp',
              'name': 'Cognitive Boost',
              'range': 'self',
              'skill': '',
              'strain_mod': '-1',
              'type': 'active'},
```

Comment: You can always use the `csv` module. The [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) class accepts a `delimiter` kwarg, that you can set to ";". Then it is a simple task of converting the dictionary that `DictReader` produces.

Comment: You are returning dict_list so none of the code below it runs and you dont make your dictionary. That isn't fixing everything, but you can probably figure it out from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another version that is a bit more drawn out, but has no dependancies.

```
file_name = "<path>/test.txt"

data = {}
with open(file_name, 'r') as test_fh:
    header_line = next(test_fh)
    header_line = header_line.strip()
    headers = header_line.split(';')

    index_headers = {index:header for index, header in enumerate(headers)}

    for line in test_fh:
        line = line.strip()
        values = line.split(';')
        index_vals = {index:val for index, val in enumerate(values)}
        data[index_vals[0]] = {index_headers[key]:value for key, value in index_vals.items() if key != 0}

print(data)
```

Comment: This ended up working. Slightly jazzed up. Put my full working script above.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy to do with `pandas`:

```
In [7]: import pandas as pd

In [8]: pd.read_clipboard(sep=";", index_col=0).T.to_dict()
Out[8]:
{'ambiencesense': {'action': 'automatic',
  'apt_bonus': nan,
  'category': 'psi-chi',
  'desc': 'This sleight provides the async with an instinctive sense about an area and any potential threats nearby. The async receives a +10 modifier to all Investigation, Perception, Scrounging, and Surprise Tests.',
  'duration': 'constant',
  'name': 'Ambience Sense',
  'range': 'self',
  'skill': nan,
  'strain_mod': 0,
  'type': 'passive'},
 'cogboost': {'action': 'quick',
  'apt_bonus': "{'COG': 5}",
  'category': 'psi-chi',
  'desc': 'The async can temporarily elevate their cognitive performance.',
  'duration': 'temp',
  'name': 'Cognitive Boost',
  'range': 'self',
  'skill': nan,
  'strain_mod': -1,
  'type': 'active'}}
```

In your case, you'd use `pd.read_csv()` instead of `.read_clipboard()` but it would look roughly the same. You might also need to tweak it a little if you want to parse the `apt_bonus` column as a dictionary.

Comment: Appreciate the answer, but I didn't want to introduce a new dependency. After looking at pandas a little more in depth, it certainly seems that it could prove very useful for a few different problems I have, so I may rethink it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this pythonic way using no libraries:

```
s = '''key;name;desc;category;type;action;range;duration;skill;strain_mod;apt_bonus
ambiencesense;Ambience Sense;This sleight provides the async with an instinctive sense about an area and any potential threats nearby. The async receives a +10 modifier to all Investigation, Perception, Scrounging, and Surprise Tests.;psi-chi;passive;automatic;self;constant;;0;
cogboost;Cognitive Boost;The async can temporarily elevate their cognitive performance.;psi-chi;active;quick;self;temp;;-1;{'COG': 5}'''

lists = [delim.split(';') for delim in s.split('\n')]
keyIndex = lists[0].index('key')
nested = {lst[keyIndex]:{lists[0][i]:lst[i] for i in range(len(lists[0])) if i != keyIndex} for lst in lists[1:]}
```

That results with:

```
{
    'cogboost': {
        'category': 'psi-chi',
        'name': 'Cognitive Boost',
        'strain_mod': '-1',
        'duration': 'temp',
        'range': 'self',
        'apt_bonus': "{'COG': 5}",
        'action': 'quick',
        'skill': '',
        'type': 'active',
        'desc': 'The async can temporarily elevate their cognitive performance.'
    },
    'ambiencesense': {
        'category': 'psi-chi',
        'name': 'Ambience Sense',
        'strain_mod': '0',
        'duration': 'constant',
        'range': 'self',
        'apt_bonus': '',
        'action': 'automatic',
        'skill': '',
        'type': 'passive',
        'desc': 'This sleight provides the async with an instinctive sense about an area and any potential threats nearby. The async receives a +10 modifier to all Investigation, Perception, Scrounging, and Surprise Tests.'
    }
}
```

Comment: I liked this short sweet solution, but I found the more verbose option easier to understand. Thanks for the tips though!